# Returning a value from a map matching the type of the return value

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors

I received the following error

```
In file included from /Users/james/ClionProjects/United States Computing Olympiad/graphs.cpp:2:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:439:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:628:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1673:31: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Vertex'
            ::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
```

And here is an abridged version of the relevant portion of my code:

```
class Vertex {
 public:
    int label;
    vector<Vertex> adjacent_vertices;
    Vertex(const int l) : label(l) { }
    Vertex(const int l, vector<Vertex> adjacents) : label(l), adjacent_vertices(adjacents) { }
    Vertex(const Vertex& other_vertex) : label(other_vertex.label), adjacent_vertices(other_vertex.adjacent_vertices){ }
};
class Graph {
 public:
    unordered_map<int, Vertex> vertices;
    protected:
    Vertex getmake_vertex(const int v) {
        if (vertices.find(v) == vertices.end() ) {
            // not found, make new vertex
            vertices[v] = Vertex(v);
        }
        return vertices[v];
    };
};
```

I have confirmed that running this with everything else commented out produces a compiler error. Can someone explain to my why this occurs and how I can fix it? [Here](https://gist.github.com/CrazyPython/82eb3322109128f777631c08de18f02a) is a gist with the full compiler output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say `vertices[v] = Vertex(v);` it has to create a `Vertex` for the key `v` (before the assignment), but `Vertex` has no default constructor.

What you should use is `vertices.insert(make_pair(v, Vertex(v)))` or even `vertices.emplace(v, Vertex(v))`

This also applies to `return vertices[v];`.  Even though you and I know that there is always a value for v already by the time this return statement is hit, the compiler doesn't and still has to generate the code to potentially make one, and that is causing an error.

Setting it to `return vertices.find(v)->second;` will fix that part.  No need to check and make sure the `find` value isn't `end` since we just put it in if it wasn't there.

Comment: The method is designed to create the vertex if it does not already exist and then return it. And since every vertex needs a label, how do I create a default constructor?

Comment: This is indeed how you do it, in case your class has no default c'tor

Comment: Yeah, that's fine.   You still keep it inside your `if (vertices.find(v)...)` block

Comment: I'm creating the vertex using the parameter `v`, which is the first constructor listed.

Comment: replacing `vertices[v] = Vertex(v)` with either of your options results in a compiler error

Comment: @CrazyPython that's why, in my answer, I specified it had to make a Vector **before** the assignment takes place.   std::map (tries to) creates a vector when you say vertices[v] if it doesn't already exist.  Then the assignment happens.   std::map::operator[] is trying to call your default constrsuctor -- the `=` bit afterwards has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @CrazyPython if you had given an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve I could have tried it for myself to see exactly what works, but you didn't, so I can't

Comment: @xaxxon OK, but the new method [here](https://gist.github.com/CrazyPython/82eb3322109128f777631c08de18f02a#file-new-method) still results in a compiler error.

Comment: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/K5JVOKJJf36JyLK5 Here's an example of how to do it

Comment: @xaxxon I stripped away all the unnecessary code and linked to the error [Here](https://gist.github.com/CrazyPython/82eb3322109128f777631c08de18f02a#file-full-minimal-code-cpp) is that + library imports + empty main method + tested for isolated error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111943/discussion-between-crazypython-and-xaxxon).

Comment: Tricky tricky... it's `return vertices[v];`  While you and I know that this will never have to create an element for `v`, the compiler doesn't know that, so it is still trying to generate the code to potentially make one.   You'll need to use `find()` again and return the value from the iterator it returns.

Comment: like so: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VTpsRlkuQYVGbEZm  std::(unordered_)map's aren't the most useful data structures from a "writing nice syntax" perspective.   multimaps are far worse.

Comment: This is "let's do in three lookups what we can do in one".

Comment: @T.C. just describing why the issue is there.   But sure you can use try_emplace and then just explicitly return the value since it's a copy anyhow.  Also, you never know which parts of the actual problem are simplified for the MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

Using `operator[]` requires the `mapped_type` (`Vertex`) in your case to be default constructible<sup>1</sup>, because it inserts a default-constructed<sup>1</sup> `mapped_type` if key doesn't exist in the map. This is a run-time decision, so even if the key actually exists you still need the default constructor at compile-time.

In C++17, use [`try_emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/try_emplace):

```
Vertex getmake_vertex(const int v) {
    return vertices.try_emplace(v, v).first->second;
}
```

Otherwise, use [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) or [`emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace).

```
Vertex getmake_vertex(const int v) {
    return vertices.insert({v, v}).first->second;
}
```

(You may need to use `Vertex(v)` if you make the `Vertex(int)` constructor `explicit`, which you probably should.)

None of those actually inserts if the key is already in the map. All three
returns a `pair<iterator, bool>` with the iterator pointing to the element with the specified key.

---

<sup>1</sup> Not quite true, but true enough for our purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If I read this part of the error message(s) correct, it requires a default constructor for `Vertex`; especially this:

> requires 2 arguments, but 0 were provided

```
/Users/james/ClionProjects/United States Computing Olympiad/graphs.cpp:14:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'l', but no arguments were provided
    Vertex(const int l) : label(l) { }
    ^
/Users/james/ClionProjects/United States Computing Olympiad/graphs.cpp:16:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'other_vertex', but no arguments were provided
    Vertex(const Vertex& other_vertex) : label(other_vertex.label), adjacent_vertices(other_vertex.adjacent_vertices){ }
    ^
/Users/james/ClionProjects/United States Computing Olympiad/graphs.cpp:15:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 0 were provided
    Vertex(const int l, vector<Vertex> adjacents) : label(l), adjacent_vertices(adjacents) { }
```